# Checkbox issue in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have below checkboxes

```
<div v-for="skill in skills">
  <div class="skill"> 
      <input type="checkbox" value="skill.skill_name" v-model="checkedSkills" @click="getVal()"/>
                <b>{{ skill.skill_name }}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I click one checkbox all checkboxes become checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be binding the `value` attribute, eg

```html
<input type="checkbox"
       :value="skill.skill_name" 
       v-model="checkedSkills" 
       @click="getVal" />
```

Otherwise, all your checkboxes have the same, static *value* of "skill.skill_name".

Second, make sure `checkedSkills` is an array and not a single, scalar value (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox)

```js
data: { // use a function if it's a component
  skills: [], // or whatever initial data you have
  checkedSkills: [] // this is the important bit
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/j4wumg5f/

Comment: Thanks @Phil for your reply. How can I use `v-model="checkedSkills"` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question